# How to apply dropConnect on recurrent weights in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am using Keras and I want to apply dropConnect on the hidden-to-hidden weights in an LSTM. I found that Keras only allows to apply dropout on the hidden states using (recurrent_dropout).

I am trying to make a custom implementation of this. I am trying to create a custom recurrent_regularizer using the following:

```
def dropConnect_reg(weight_matrix):
    return tf.nn.dropout(weight_matrix, rate = 0.5)
```

then use it as follows (the task is language modelling, so I apply a softmax layer on the vocab):

```
model.add(LSTM(650, return_sequences=True, recurrent_regularizer=dropConnect_reg))
model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax'))
```

However, I don't think this works properly. Without using the implemented recurrent_regularizer the loss is a scalar number as expected (the categorical cross-entropy loss). However, when using it, it outputs a full array for the loss instead of having only one number (dimensions: time_steps,time_steps*4). I am also currently not sure if this is applied during training only as it is intended.

Any ideas on how to properly implement this?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the last output from the LSTM, you'll want to set `return_sequences=False`. If you only want to apply the dropout during training you'll need something like this:

```py
def dropconnect_regularizer(weight_matrix):
  return tf.nn.dropout(weight_matrix, rate=0.5)

if training:
  regularizer = dropconnect_regularizer
else:
  regularizer = None

model.add(LSTM(650, recurrent_regularizer=regularizer))
```